# Create a ZipFile in memory and attach it to an email

Tags: python, python-2.7, email-attachments, in-memory, python-zipfile

I'm trying to modify an existing python script to convert an in-memory CSV into an (also in memory) zip archive and send it as an attachment to an email. I've had success attaching an in memory CSV file (via a MIMEText object) but am having trouble with the ZIP file (via a MIMEBase object) due to the requirements to setting the payload of the file's bytes.

This is the code I have so far:

```
csv_buffer = cStringIO.StringIO()
buffer = cStringIO.StringIO()

zf = zipfile.ZipFile(buffer,
               mode='w',
               compression=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED,
               )

zf.writestr(csvfile + ".csv", csv_buffer.getvalue())


csv_file = MIMEBase('application', 'zip')
csv_file.set_payload(zf.read())
encoders.encode_base64(csv_file)
csv_file.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment',
         filename=csvfile + ".zip")

msg.attach(csv_file)
```

From this [This user's most upvoted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10474650/how-to-send-a-zip-file-as-an-attachment-in-python) I could fix the `read() takes at least 2 arguments` error I'm receiving by doing a normal `open()` operation on the zip file but since this file is a buffered stream that doesn't work.

I'm not sure how else to load the `zipfile` object into the `set_payload` but that should also work I would think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `read` method of a `ZipFile` object is meant to read the content of a named file within the zip file.

You should use the content of `buffer` instead after you write to the buffer with the `writestr` method of the `ZipFile` instance:

```
csv_file.set_payload(buffer.getvalue())
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I knew there was a simple answer and this is certainly that!